# add values to textbox history without submitting the form using javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, browser-history

Hello friends I have a `<input type="text" id="tempID" />` element in my form

I also have an `<input type="button" onclick="doSomething()" />` element in my form.

I want to add the text box value to textbox history when user clicks on the button.

I am processing the request using Jquery ajax. So I have to do it with javascript or Jquery.

Is this possible to add values to the history of particular `<input type="text" />` element using javascript/Jquery..??

Comment: Nop, there isn't any for adding values to history of an element. But you can maintain an special `array` and `push` values to that each time user clicks and then pull that back when needed.

Comment: @Joy but the values in array will lose when user refreshes the page. Is there any alternate..??

Comment: Then you have add that into cookie, if you want that to persist between requests. You can use this plugin https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: @Joy ok.. but how will I show them when start typing or double click inside textbox (when empty). Please refer any good article if u have one.

Comment: Do you want a autocomplete type of thing and track all previous values or just the last one?

Comment: yes @Joy.. I want to track all previous values, until user do not clear form saved data from browser memory manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do it using HTML5 LocalStorage

```
$( "#tempID" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( req, resp ) {

    var temp = localStorage.getItem('custom_history');  

    var data = JSON.parse(temp);
    resp( data );

}
});


$('#tempID').on('blur', function() {
    var temp = localStorage.getItem('custom_history');  

    var data = JSON.parse(temp); 
    if($.trim(this.value).length > 0)
       data.push(this.value);

    localStorage.setItem('custom_history', JSON.stringify(data));
```

});

What I am doing is Setting the value into HTML5 Local storage when users moves away from the input field, clicks somewhere else.

Then retrieving that and setting that as source for jQuery UI auto complete.

Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/EBduF/173/

Enter some value. Click somewhere else. Click back again and add other values. The refresh the fiddle and start typing one of those and auto complete will show up.

**UPDATE**

Based on his comments and later chat the final code he need is this, I am pasting in if it might someone else later

```
// if we dont set this line then ff will return null, and null.length will throw an error
if(!localStorage.getItem('custom_history'))
        localStorage.setItem('custom_history','');
 $( "#test" ).autocomplete({
    source: function( req, resp ) {
      var term = req.term;
      var temp = localStorage.getItem('custom_history');  
        var data = [];
        if(temp.length > 0)
           data = JSON.parse(temp);
       var intRegex = /^\d+$/; 
       data = $.map(data,function(val){
                if(intRegex.test(val)){
                   if(val.indexOf(term) != -1) 
                        return val;
                   else
                        return null;
                }
                else
                    return null;
             });
      resp( data );

    }
});


$('#save').on('click', function() {
    var temp = localStorage.getItem('custom_history'); 

      var data = [];
      if(temp.length > 0)
        data = JSON.parse(temp); 
      var value = $.trim($('#test').val());
      if(value.length > 0){
         if($.inArray(value,data) != -1){
             //alert('Duplicate'); 
             return;
         }

      }
      data.push(value);
      localStorage.setItem('custom_history', JSON.stringify(data)); // set item to localStorage
});
```

Comment: there is an error in your fiddle error is data is null. I am using firefox 12.0  @Joy

Comment: check this it's not working in fiddle for some reason http://joynag.net/demos/localstorage/ Try it in the same way, input something, click somewhere else, click back and add something new then refresh and start typing

Comment: it is working.. but can you please do something to avoid duplicates..?? @joy

Comment: Updated the above demo, now you will get an alert when it finds a duplicate, you can easily comment out that alert in your code. :)

Comment: Sorry to make u little irritate. Your demo is working, But I tried to implement this on https://www.bobdn.com/HTMLPage1.htm. Can u pleeease find where is the error in this..??

Comment: It's fine lets move to chat and fix this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11454/discussion-between-joy-and-new-to-stackoverflow)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localStorage` like following:

```
var arr = [];
$('input#tempID').on('click', function() {
   arr.push(this.value);
   localStorage.setItem('history', JSON.stringify(arr)); // set item to localStorage
});
```

To retrieve that value try,

```
var temp = localStorage.getItem('history');

if(retarr) { // checking that data it stored in localStorage or not, if not exists temp = null
  var allHistories = JSON.parse(temp); // now you have history
  console.log(allHistories);
}
```

I think you need something like [**autocomplete**](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/)

Comment: I dont think this is what he is asking for.

Comment: I know how to make ajax request on button click. I want to know
`add values to textbox history without submitting the form using javascript or Jquery` as in question title.

Comment: @thecodeparadox but how will I show them when user start typing or double click inside textbox (when empty). Please refer any good article if u have one